# How to restrict python input to only allow letters and space

Tags: python, input

This is my current code:

```
while True:
    name = input("Please enter your name: ")
    if name.isalpha() and name.isspace(): #fix to allow space
        break
    if name.isalpha():
        break
    else:
        print("Error")
```

The issue is that it raises an error if the input is "Bob Dole", as the inputs of "Bob" or "James" is working fine. How do I make sure it allows a full name esque input?

Comment: `isspace()` is only `True` if the string contains _only_ whitespace characters and is at least length 1. Perhaps you should split your string and then check if each component `isalpha`? Or replace all `' '` with `''` and determine if the resultant string `isalpha()`? I don't know what you want to do with the `name` so these suggestions may not work.

Comment: Do not vandalize your posts. By posting on this site, you've irrevocably granted the Stack Exchange network the right to distribute that content under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/) for as long as it sees fit to do so. For alternatives to deletion, see: [I've thought better of my question; can I delete it?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question)

Answer (score 0):

This will test by character instead of by word as you're currently doing;

```
if all((char.isalpha() or char==' ') for char in name):
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead, use two validations, use the or clause and check each character that you received from input, for example:

```
while True:
    name = input("Please enter your name: ")
    if all(x.isalpha() or x.isspace() for x in name):
        break
    else:
        print("Error")
```

Answer (score 0):

`isalpha` and `isspace` functions check if the string ONLY comprises of alpha and space characters, respectively. A "Bob Dole" string will return False to both `isalpha` and `isspace` functions.

You may have to use `isalpha` and `isspace` functions on each letter of the name, and use `all` function to check if all characters satisfy the condition. Alternatively, you can just use `for`/`while` loop to iterate each letter and check against `isalpha` and `isspace` accordingly.

```
while True:
    name = input("Please enter your name: ")
    if all([letter.isalpha() or letter.isspace() for letter in name]):
        break
    else:
        print("Error")
```

Answer (score 0):

From @wkl's comment...

```
while True:
     name = input("Please enter your name: ")
     if name.isalpha():
          break
     if all(each.isalpha() for each in name.split()):
          break
     else:
          print("Error")
```

This should work just fine :)

Comment: Thanks! How would i raise the error if the input is blank though

Comment: You can modify the second condition to `if all(each.isalpha() for each in name.split()) and len(name) > 0`